# Code not getting updated and how to know whether iteration is happening?

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, google-cloud-functions

My firebase-database structure is below: 
[image: firebase-database structure]

And my function code in node.js:

```
exports.addFunction = functions.database
    .ref('/Users/{uid}/GyroScope X-axis')
    .onWrite(event => {

var add = 0;
const addGyroX = admin.database().ref('/GyroXaddition');
const userRef = event.data.adminRef;  

userRef.once('value').then(snapshot => {
  snapshot.forEach(childrensnap => {
      var reading = childrensnap.key;
      var childData = reading.val();
      add = add+childData;
      return addGyroX.set(childData); 
    });
  });
});
```

My plan is to iterate through values of GyroScope X-axis and update the value to a newly created path (GyroXaddition) as it iterates. I'm not getting any error but it is'nt updating either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you've provided will definitely not work and likely throw lots of errors. Here's a few things I noticed:

1. You're not returning your Promise, which will cause you problems.
2. Your `forEach` is out of position and needs to be called inside the function body.
3. Your `set` is referencing data from a different scope (also if you're trying to iterate over multiple values, that `.set` is just going to be using the last value).
4. `event.data.adminRef` is the proper capitalization.
5. `snapshot.key` not `snapshot.key()`

This snippet fixes *some* of the problems, but I'm not sure what you're trying to do to get you all the way there.

```
return userRef.once('value').then(snap => {
  var sets = [];

  snap.forEach(childsnapshot => {
    var reading = childsnapshot.key;
    var childData = reading.val();
  });
});
```

Comment: He doesn't actually have a Promise, so he can just return like normal.

Comment: Thanks, but it did'nt throw any error while deploying the code. Then how do I know if there's any error, I use VS code editor. And I've made changes to the code with your suggestions and still doesn't work. My plan is to just iterate through the GyroScope X-axis values under it and add the values like in 1st iteration(0.004...555 from fig) and in second iteration(0.002...645) and update the result to different path if exists or create the path and set the result.

Comment: Can you tell what's the problem in the updated code, if possible, I've been struggling with this since a day and half?

Answer (score 0):

Because you are not waiting for the asynchronous calling to return a value. When grabbing your data and setting `childData`, it takes longer than normal. When using asynchronous programming, multiple threads will be going at the same time. In your code, the value addGyroX was being returned, even though childData did not exist. Therefore, in order to return the correct value, please use this code

```
exports.addFunction =
functions.database .ref('/Users/{uid}/GyroScope X-axis') .onWrite(event => { 
  const addGyroX = admin.database().ref('/GyroXaddition'); 
  const userRef = event.data.adminref;
  userRef.once('value').then(forEach(childsnapshot => { 
    var reading = childsnapshot.key(); 
    var childData = reading.val(); 
    return addGyroX.set(childData);
  })
); 
});
```

This way, addGyroX will only return when a value has been received.